# How to define column order for non-clustered index

Tags: sql-server-2008, non-clustered-index

I have written a subquery that goes like this:

```
select top 1 A
from my_table
where B = some_joined_value_from_outer_query
order by C desc
```

I want to create a non-clustered index that would improve performance on this part.

3 questions here:

1. What would be the correct order for the indexed columns?
2. Also, should column A be an indexed column or just included in the index?
3. Can this be rewritten without a subquery (notice the `top 1` and `order by desc`) and could that improve performance?

---

**EDIT:**
Here's the query (part of a data synchronisation process):

```
SELECT ProductId, (
    SELECT Id 
    FROM [Order]
    WHERE Number = (
        SELECT TOP 1 OrderNumber
        FROM OtherDatabase..ReferenceTable
        WHERE ProductNumber = Product.Number
        ORDER BY [Date] DESC)
    ) AS OrderId
FROM Product
```

Comment: Based on the information provided it is impossible to say if this could be improved without a subquery. Try various methods, check your execution plans for each and run tests.

Comment: What is the purpose of the query? To find all the products in the most recent order? Is there an index on the `[date]` column?

Comment: We want to update references in our own database based on this reference table (which works with textual numbers instead of id's). The date column is the column "C" in the example above. It has the index that you suggested.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

(A)

```
CREATE NONCLUSTERED INDEX foo ON dbo.my_table(B, C DESC) INCLUDE (A);
```

(B)

Since A is not in `WHERE` or `ORDER BY`, it is probably sufficient to be in the list of `INCLUDE`d columns, since it's just "along for the ride" and not necessary to be part of the key.

(C)

Impossible to answer without more context. Why would you only include the subquery then ask about an outer query we can't see?

**EDIT** with regard to the ongoing conversation with @Quassnoi, I just wanted to demonstrate quickly that the sort direction of trailing columns in a non-clustered index *can* make a big difference on the plans used by a particular query. Let's take the following contrived example:

```
CREATE TABLE dbo.foo1(A INT, B INT, C INT);
CREATE NONCLUSTERED INDEX foo1x ON dbo.foo1(B, C) INCLUDE(A);

CREATE TABLE dbo.foo2(A INT, B INT, C INT);
CREATE NONCLUSTERED INDEX foo2x ON dbo.foo2(B, C DESC) INCLUDE(A);

INSERT dbo.foo1 SELECT TOP (500000) c.[object_id], c.[object_id], -1*c.[object_id]
FROM sys.all_columns AS c CROSS JOIN sys.all_objects
ORDER BY c.[object_id];

INSERT dbo.foo2 SELECT TOP (500000) c.[object_id], c.[object_id], -1*c.[object_id]
FROM sys.all_columns AS c CROSS JOIN sys.all_objects
ORDER BY c.[object_id];
```

Now, let's run these two proposed queries and inspect the plans:

```
SELECT  A
FROM    (
        SELECT  A, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY B ORDER BY C DESC) RN
        FROM    dbo.foo1
        ) q
WHERE   rn = 1;

SELECT  A
FROM    (
        SELECT  A, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY B ORDER BY C DESC) RN
        FROM    dbo.foo2
        ) q
WHERE   rn = 1;
```

---

Here's the plan for the query against dbo.foo1 (where C is ASC):

[image]

[image]

And the sort I mentioned:

[image]

---

And here's the plan for the query against dbo.foo2 (where C is DESC):

[image]

[image]

---

Now, if you add a WHERE clause to the inner query (e.g. WHERE B = -1024577103), the plans are more similar. But then that also implies that the PARTITION BY is unnecessary and that there needs to be some matching involved to limit the outer query to that value of B also. However my point is still that while for the specific query in the question, the sort direction of each column in an index might have little effect on the plan, but this is not true for all queries that could use the same index.

Comment: For this very query, `C ASC` would behave just the same.

Comment: About the subquery, it is used in the select list of the outer query. So it has to return one result (or NULL)...

Comment: @Quassnoi while true for the plan itself, the definition of the index better describes its intention (the query it was built to satisfy). Are you sure this behavior holds true for very large numbers of identical values for B?

Comment: @Keon yes, I understand, but we can't look at the subquery alone and say "Ooh, this will be faster" without more context. So if you want to ask a question about how to make the whole query better, post the whole query.

Comment: Thanks for the answer complete answer. I have the index as explained. Still it takes me over 1 hour to select around 600.000 records which I think can be improved. Have posted the full query so maybe you see some improvements there...

Answer (score 0):

Order does matter. The column which is at first order is the most important.

The selection of index is entirely based on first column. An index is considered for use only if the first column listed in the index is used in the query. So if there is no match on first column and column is used in JOIN, ORDER BY, or WHERE clauses of the query, index is completely ignored.

Answer (score 0):

You could rewrite it like this:

```
SELECT  m.a
FROM    (
        SELECT  m.a, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY m.b ORDER BY m.c DESC) RN
        FROM    outer_table o
        JOIN    my_table m
        ON      m.b = o.b
        ) q
WHERE   rn = 1
```

but the subquery may actually be faster (or may not).

See this entry in my blog:

- [**SQL Server: Selecting records holding group-wise maximum**](http://explainextended.com/2009/11/30/sql-server-selecting-records-holding-group-wise-maximum/)

Comment: For *this* query, you should compare the plan against an index with C ASC and an index with C DESC. For the index where C is ASC, there is an extra (and rather expensive) sort operation required, and depending on other factors this could spill to tempdb (make sure there are a sufficient number of rows). This is why I like my index where C is DESC - for some queries, it does make a big difference. (As an added bonus, make sure to try it on a system where parallelism will kick in. :-))

Comment: @Aaron: the index can be traversed in both directions, and `C` is trailing. `DESC` or `ASC` will make no difference here.